# Why is the time complexity of Heapsort O(n logn) and not O(log(n!))?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory, heapsort

Heapsort, every time it iterates within, the heapsize reduces by one, and hence should have a time complexity of `Sigma(i=N to 1) O(log i)` which would result in `O(log n!)`. And why can't we just report the time complexity of Heapsort as `O(log n!)`.

I came across **Stirling's Approximation** while trying to answer this question, and realised that `log n! -> n logn` as `n -> inf`. Also, is the reason why we agree upon `O(n logn)` instead of `O(log n!)`, even though `log(n!)` is smaller than `n logn` for a wide range of values?

Comment: O(n log n) is the same as O(log n!)

Comment: n log n has some advantages over log n! (it's more easily computable, and allows easy comparison with other comparison-based sort algorithms). Sedgewick in various of his books does more exact calculations of the number of comparisons performed by various algorithms, which is maybe what you're interested in rather than big-O.

Comment: Sorry, but I voted to close the question. I don't think it's really answerable because it's either going to be a study of history (how we came to choose n log n over log n!) or a weighing of subjective considerations.

Comment: O(N Log N) and O(Log N!) are asymptotically equivalent, full stop. By the way, if you want to be picky, every heap reduction has a cost proportional to Ceiling(Log(N)) and a total of Log N! is not "more accurate".